CurveFitting with more than 5 parameters in C#
I would like to fit a curve with 6 parameters using C#. To do this I am using MathNet.Numerics.Fit.Curve. But since it only supports up to 5 parameters, I tried to set one parameter of the function to the guess value and fit the other parameters.
To fit the value that was previously fixed, I set another value, that was fitted, as a fixed value and fit again. This concept works fine for most of the data, but it still fails sometimes.
I would like to know if someone has any idea how I could implement the MathNet.Numerics.Fit.Curve for 6 parameters, since I think this would resolve my problem.
Thanks

What is the actual goal? If the function is a polynomial you have Fit.Polynomial with arbitrary order. If you want to fit a bezier curve I'm not sure Math.Net is sufficient, see How can I fit a Bézier curve to a set of data

Its a resonance function for a piezo component, so Polynomial wont work

No data, no code, hence no [mcve].

If you want to test MathNet.Fit for your more-than five parameters
model, we can create a version of Fit.Curve
that takes a function with a dynamic number of parameters. That means
the model will be a function of type
Func<Vector<double>, double, double> - the first
argument, is the vector of parameters and the second argument the
current value of x coordinate.
We may start by taking a look at the source code of Fit.Curve implementations;
they are based on corresponding versions of FindMinimum.OfFunction;
fortunately, while there's no dynamic-number-of-parameters version
of Fit.Curve, there is one
for FindMinimum.OfFunctions. Using this version and the general approach from
existing Fit.Curve versions our function could be written as
simple as:
static Vector<double> FitCurve2(double[] x, double[] y, Func<Vector<double>, double, double> f, Vector<double> initialGuess, double tolerance = 1e-8, int maxIterations = 1000) {
    return FindMinimum.OfFunction((p) => Distance.Euclidean(Generate.Map(x, t => f(p, t)), y), initialGuess, tolerance, maxIterations);
}


Here's an example of this function being used to fit a 6 parameter curve. The model function here is F1, a rational function with parameters
q0, ..., q5. I start with a set of known values of these parameters
q0 = 1.596, q1 = -1.277, ..... (all these from an application of mine,
consider them random for the purpose of this test) and generate a
set of x, y0 arrays that match these parameters. Then add some
random noise to y0 and fit the resulting x, y for the model
function. If all goes well, we'll retrieve some parameters q0, ..., q5
that are close to the original ones, which we usually do.
using MathNet.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

const int n = 200;
const double q0 = 1.596, q1 = -1.277, q2 = -4.33, q3 = 0.5, q4 = 1, q5 = 1.4; // "clear" parameters

var x = Generate.LinearSpaced(n, -3, 3);
var rnd = new double[n];
Normal.Samples(rnd, 0.0, 1.0);
var y0 = Generate.Map(x, xi=>F1(q0, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, xi));
var y = Generate.Map2(y0, rnd, (yi, ri) => yi + ri * 0.2); // y0 + noise
Vector<double> initialGuess = DenseVector.OfArray([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]);
var q = FitCurve2(x, y, (q, x) => F1(q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3], q[4], q[5], x),
    initialGuess, 1e-9, 10000);
Console.WriteLine($"q0 = {q[0]}  q1 = {q[1]}  q2 = {q[2]}  q3 = {q[3]}  q4 = {q[4]}  q5 = {q[5]}");
// parameters impacted by noise, still close the "clear" ones.

double F1(double q0, double q1, double q2, double q3, double q4, double q5, double x)
{
    return (q0 + q1 * x + q2 * Math.Pow(x, 2) + q3  * Math.Pow(x, 3) +  q4 * Math.Pow(x, 4))/(x*x + q5);
}

static Vector<double> FitCurve2(double[] x, double[] y, Func<Vector<double>, double, double> f, Vector<double> initialGuess, double tolerance = 1e-8, int maxIterations = 1000) {
    return FindMinimum.OfFunction((p) => Distance.Euclidean(Generate.Map(x, t => f(p, t)), y), initialGuess, tolerance, maxIterations);
}

Here's a chart image of this fit.

Note that it can be verified that if one uses less than 6 parameters
the computed results are identical to those computed by the
static-number-of-parameter versions of Fit.Curve (of course, if
all other parameters like initial guess, tolerance or max iterations
being equal).
That being said, one should note that MathNet is not the only
library that can do nonlinear curve fitting in C# and dotNet. Of
course, stackoverflow doesn't allow
seeking recommendations for libraries,
nor am I best qualified to give some. Just consider the eventuality
that if a curve fitting doesn't work out as expected, the problem
might not always be your model, but it can also be the algorithms
used by the library, and in such case one might as well test other libs too.
